# Is it possible to change the font size of the app name displayed under the app icon?

Tags: ios

I've seen apps that have more characters than mine and displayed fully whereas mine starts to truncate with the "..." after its 10th char.

I know an app on my iPhone that has 14 characters, and they are all displayed without any "...". I noticed that app's app title's fonts are a little bit smaller and the char-spacing in between is much less compared to the other apps.

Comment: better contact apple for this @ devprograms@apple.com They are right people to give you answer for this...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. The actual size isn't measured by chars because every char has a different width.
Your app name probably has more "boldy" chars that resulting in less char count than the one you mentioned.

BTW
The OS is shrinking app names when it tries to fit it completely under the app icon, but this also has a limit of course.

Answer (score 0):

The font they use for application name is not monospace (or fixed-width). Means, the length of the name depends on the characters: M & W take more space than I & T.

Yes, there is no way to choose the font. But you might come up with a workaround.
As an option you can replace a whitespace with a thinner one as explained [here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons).

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the app name is very difficult. Find a short name. You can also put a part of your app name directly in the app's icon.